# What does "__JVM_DefineClass__" as a classloader location mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, classloader

I am debugging the reason as to why eclipse cannot load the source code when remote debugging  dynamically compiled and loaded classes. I am seeing with the `-verbose:class` argument that my dynamically compiled class files are coming from `__JVM_DefineClass__`. I assume this to mean that they come from the JVM heapspace itself, as I have the compiler output the compiled bytes into a "FileManager" that caches the compiled bytes in memory.

It seems that the only way for the source to be view-able when debugging is if I specify in the source lookup path where the actual loaded class came from... and it doesn't seem to work if I specify the directory where the class is being compiled from. I feel that if I save the compiled bytes to disk, the source loading might work.

So, what does `__JVM_DefineClass__` mean? Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a location URL was not included in the CodeSource in the ProtectionDomain when defineClass was called by the ClassLoader.  This could be because the class was dynamically generated, but it could also be because the ClassLoader simply didn't provide the information when it defined the class.

Comment: digging through the source/javadoc related to this now... are you familiar with how I would manually specify this location?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in Eclipse. If you have access to the ClassLoader that is defining the class, you could adjust it to set the CodeSource location.

Comment: yes, I do have access to the classloader that is defining the class ( I wrote the logic myself ). I'll hammer around on it and see what happens, thx!

Comment: If you started with a File (e.g., c:/classpath/test.jar or the base c:/classpath/directory/ containing com/example/classes/Foo.class), then use File.toURI().toURL(), then use it to create a CodeSource, then use it to create a ProtectionDomain, and use that when calling ClassLoader.defineClass.

Comment: I start with `.java` files and compile using `JavaCompiler.getTask().call()`. Do I provide the path to the .class file or the .java file? My .class file is actually just stored inside a hashmap, the compiler task does not output to disk so I don't have a File reference.

Comment: You would normally provide the directory specified by the `javac -d` option, but since the files are not on disk, specifying a null location is technically the correct thing to do.  As a workaround, you could try specifying the src directory to see if that helps Eclipse.  I think it would be technically superior to leave the null location and somehow configure the source directory for Eclipse, I just don't know how to do that.