# How do I re-encode dynamically compiled bytes to text?

Tags: java, dynamic, character-encoding, compilation

Consider the following[(Sourced primarily from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889793/java-loading-and-unloading-java-files-dynamically-garbage-collection):

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler( );
JavaFileManager manager = new MemoryFileManager( compiler.getStandardFileManager( null, null, null ) );

compiler.getTask( null, manager, null, null, null, sourceScripts ).call( ); //sourceScripts is of type List<ClassFile>
```

And the following file manager :

```
public class MemoryFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager< JavaFileManager > {
    private HashMap< String, ClassFile > classes = new HashMap<>( );

    public MemoryFileManager( StandardJavaFileManager standardManager ) {
        super( standardManager );
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader( Location location ) {
        return new SecureClassLoader( ) {
            @Override
            protected Class< ? > findClass( String className ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                if ( classes.containsKey( className ) ) {
                    byte[ ] classFile = classes.get( className ).getClassBytes( );
                    System.out.println(new String(classFile, "utf-8"));
                    return super.defineClass( className, classFile, 0, classFile.length );
                } else throw new ClassNotFoundException( );
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public ClassFile getJavaFileForOutput( Location location, String className, Kind kind, FileObject sibling ) {
        if ( classes.containsKey( className ) ) return classes.get( className );
        else {
            ClassFile classObject = new ClassFile( className, kind );
            classes.put( className, classObject );
            return classObject;
        }
    }
}

public class ClassFile extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private byte[ ] source;
    protected final ByteArrayOutputStream compiled = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

    public ClassFile( String className, byte[ ] contentBytes ) {
        super( URI.create( "string:///" + className.replace( '.', '/' ) + Kind.SOURCE.extension ), Kind.SOURCE );
        source = contentBytes;
    }

    public ClassFile( String className, CharSequence contentCharSequence ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super( URI.create( "string:///" + className.replace( '.', '/' ) + Kind.SOURCE.extension ), Kind.SOURCE );
        source = ( ( String )contentCharSequence ).getBytes( "UTF-8" );
    }

    public ClassFile( String className, Kind kind ) {
        super( URI.create( "string:///" + className.replace( '.', '/' ) + kind.extension ), kind );
    }

    public byte[ ] getClassBytes( ) {
        return compiled.toByteArray( );
    }

    public byte[ ] getSourceBytes( ) {
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent( boolean ignoreEncodingErrors ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String( source, "UTF-8" );
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream openOutputStream( ) {
        return compiled;
    }
}
```

Stepping through the code, on the compiler.getTask().call(), the first thing that happens here is getJavaFileForOutput() is called, and then the getClassLoader() method is called to load the class, which yields in the compiled bytes being written to console.

Why does that println in the getClassLoader() method yield an amalgamation of my working compiled bytecode(primarily strings, it appears the actual bytecode instruction keywords are not here) and random gibberish? This leads me to believe that I was using too short a UTF so I tried UTF-16, and it looked more or less similar. How do I encode the bytes back into text? I am aware that using the SimpleJavaFileManager would be straightforward enough but I need to be able to use this example of caching(without the possible memory leaks of course) for performance purposes.

Edit: 
And yes, the compiled code does classload and run perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does that println in the getClassLoader() method yield an amalgamation of my working compiled bytecode(primarily strings, it appears the actual bytecode instruction keywords are not here) and random gibberish?

Without seeing the so-called "random gibberish", I would surmise that what you are seeing is the well-formed binary content of a class file that has been "decoded" as a String in some character set.

That ain't going to work.  It is a binary format, and you can't expect to turn it into text like that and have it display as something readable.

(And for what it is worth, a ".class" file would not contain keywords for the JVM opcodes, any more than a ".exe" file would contain keywords for machine instructions.  It is **binary**!)

---

If you want to see the compiled code in text form, then save the bytes in that byte array to a file, and use the `javap` utility to look at it.  (I'll leave you to look up the command line syntax for the `javap` command ... )

Comment: Aha, oh man that was a major derp. Sorry. Anyways, in that case, is there some sort of decoder for their encoding? I can open .class files in eclipse and list the opcodes so it must be possible.